# Cannot execute catkin_make in githook

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, ros-kinetic, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a `pre-push` [githook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) that tries to execute `catkin_make` before pushing, to only allow pushes that (at least) can compile. It works by git invoking invoking a bash script and depending on the return code allowing or denying the push "request". The githook is invoked locally: nothing is run on the server. The script looks like this (only the important parts):

```
#!/bin/bash

# "This hook is called by git push and can be used to prevent a push from taking place.
#  If this hook exits with a non-zero status, git push will abort without pushing anything. 
#  Information about why the push is rejected may be sent to the user by writing to standard error."
# see: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

# make the script fail if any line fails, see: http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/
set -euo pipefail

# go to the project root
# taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1571525/3753684
repo_root=$( git rev-parse --show-toplevel )
cd $repo_root

# build the project once
# this still prints output *on error*, which is what we want
build_output=$( catkin_make )
build_exit_status=$?

if [ $build_exit_status -eq 0 ];

    then # it worked, let git push it

        # log success message 
        echo "build succeeded, pushing is allowed"

        # exit successfully
        exit 0

    else # it failed, prevent git from pushing

        # log fail message
        echo -e "--------------------\n\n"
        echo "Failed to build the project. Not pushing."
        
        # exit non-successfully
        exit $build_exit_status

fi
```

When I execute it in the terminal by hand, everything works just fine. But when git invokes it, this error gets printed out: ".git/hooks/pre-push: line 19: catkin_make: command not found". Line 19 is the one containing `build_output=$( catkin_make )`. It strangely works on another machine having pretty much the same setup. We both have ROS Kinetic installed on Ubuntu LTS 16.04 and Kubuntu LTS 16.04.

What am I doing wrong?

I think catkin_make itself cannot be found. I have this in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source /home/felix/sailing/bord-pc/devel/setup.bash
export BORD_PC_WORKSPACE=/home/felix/sailing/bord-pc # this is my workspace
```

And sourcing it in the script and/or in the subshell in line 19 did not work:

```
source ~/.bashrc
build_output=$( source ~/.bashrc && catkin_make )
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269240/cannot-execute-catkin_make-in-githook/) by [felixd](https://answers.ros.org/users/31644/felixd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally found the solution:

I had to add `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` directly in the subshell, the indirect sourcing through the `~./bashrc` did not work for some reason. Is that a bug?

Working solution:

```
build_output=$( source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash && catkin_make )
```

Thanks @gvdhoorn for your support.

EDIT:
This is why it didn't work:

This was the output of git invoking the githook script: `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.sh: line 47: TMPDIR: unbound variable`. Which is usually not a problem, but the strict script rules enforced by `set -euo pipefail` caused it to crash.

---

Originally posted by [felixd](https://answers.ros.org/users/31644/felixd/) with karma: 26 on 2017-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-21**:
Could've solved this a lot sooner then. This is what I wrote in comment 4:

> Try `$(source .. && catkin_make)`.

Good to hear you got it to work.

**Comment by [felixd](https://answers.ros.org/users/31644/felixd/) on 2017-08-21**:
Hm yeah, I thought you meant sourcing the ~/.bashrc ... which somehow didn't work.
But thanks! :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-21**:\

> the indirect sourcing through the `~./bashrc` did not work for some reason. Is that a bug?

No, that is probably because the `bash` session that is running the hook is not *interactive*, as I wrote in my own answer. Check your `.bashrc`, you'll find the following lines at ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-21**:
.. the top of the file (at least on Ubuntu):

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't tell us what doesn't work, but assuming that you're getting complaints from `catkin_make` that it can't find certain ROS pkgs *or* that `catkin_make` itself can't be found: do you `source /path/to/the/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` (or equivalent for `/opt/ros/$distro/setup.bash`) before invoking `catkin_make`?

---

Edit:

> I think catkin_make itself cannot be found. I have this in my ~/.bashrc:

> ```
> source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
> ```

```
source /home/felix/sailing/bord-pc/devel/setup.bash
export BOARD_PC_WORKSPACE=/home/felix/sailing/bord-pc
```

And is your `$HOME/.bashrc` used by whatever/who-ever is running the git server? If not, your `.bashrc` will not have any influence.

---

Edit2:  <del>So you have a `pre-push` hook that is run locally?</del>

seems I missed that. Ignore all the server stuff then.

But the question remains: if the `bash` session this is run in is non-interactive, your `.bashrc` will not be seen.

Can you print the contents of `$PATH` in the hook?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-21**:
And if you were my server admin, I'd very quickly start complaining that my pushes to your server are taking on the order of 5 min+ with any decent ROS project/application. Pushes should be fast.

Would checking the state of your code not be the responsibility of CI infrastructure?

**Comment by [felixd](https://answers.ros.org/users/31644/felixd/) on 2017-08-21**:
Sorry, I immediately edited the question bu you were to fast. ;)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-21**:
Please add additional information to your original question. Comments are not suited for that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-21**:
Try `$(source .. && catkin_make)`.

**Comment by [felixd](https://answers.ros.org/users/31644/felixd/) on 2017-08-21**:
exactly that didn't work either

**Comment by [felixd](https://answers.ros.org/users/31644/felixd/) on 2017-08-21**:
Ohhh, now I get the comments about the server: The githook is invoked locally! Nothing is run on the server.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-21**:
Additionally: if the `bash` session that runs your hook is non-interactive, your `.bashrc` (or the one from the user that runs the git server) will not be sourced.

You could try adding something like `source /path/to/the/.bashrc` at the top.

**Comment by [felixd](https://answers.ros.org/users/31644/felixd/) on 2017-08-21**:
That didn't work either. See my edit in the question at the bottom.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-21**:
Tbh this isn't really a ROS problem afaics. The `catkin_make` binary is basically not on your `$PATH`, that seems to be the issue.

**Comment by [felixd](https://answers.ros.org/users/31644/felixd/) on 2017-08-21**:
My `$PATH`: `/usr/lib/git-core:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-21**:
And that is *in* the session that runs the hook?

**Comment by [felixd](https://answers.ros.org/users/31644/felixd/) on 2017-08-21**:
Yes. I put in the script, and tried to push something.